# Matlab: Reading values from a variable?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to read from my input file (`test_input.txt`) some specific data. I need this data for calculations and settings.

Everything works except the input variable `wsectionstart` from my `test_input.txt` file.

When I run the entire code, I get the output message:

> `wsectionstart = NaN`

My question is how can I read this variable without any error messages. So I can read every single value from `wsectionstart` like `wsectionstart(1)` or `wsectionstart(2)`. How should I modify my code?

The following code is just a small reduced part from my whole code:

```
diagramoptions = []; 

wholecontent = fileread('test_input.txt');

sections = regexp(wholecontent, '\*+([^*]+)\*+([^*]+)', 'tokens');

for section = sections

   switch(strtrim(section{1}{1})) 

       case 'Diagram Options'

          keyvalues = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens'); %\n -> new line; \r carriage return

          diagramoptions = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'});

        otherwise

            warning('Unknown section: %s', section{1}{1}),

     end

  end

linewidth=str2double(diagramoptions.Value(strcmp(diagramoptions.Key, 'linewidth'))); %works

xlabel=diagramoptions.Value(strcmp(diagramoptions.Key, 'xlabel')); %works

wsectionstart=str2double(diagramoptions.Value(strcmp(diagramoptions.Key, 'wsectionstart')))
```

And this is my `test_input.txt` File

```
******************* Diagram Options****************
linewidth=12
wsectionstart=1000000 3000000 
xlabel= Capture
```

Comment: What is the expected output?  What values in your text file do you want to save and how do you want them stored? It's very difficult to determine this from your code.

Comment: The variable "wsectionstart" has two values -> see test.txt. I want to read the first value and the second value and store them in an array.

Comment: you say your file is called `test_input.txt` but then in your code you load it as `test.txt`... which is it?

Comment: sorry i test_input.txt should be right :/

Comment: Is that the error in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code which:

- Reads in the `txt` file as a table using `readtable`
- Converts the relevant values from strings to numbers using `str2double`
- Assigns all input variables based on those in the file

  ```
  % Create table from formatted input txt file (see below)
  T = table2array(readtable('test_input.txt'));

  % Initialise & populate variables from table
  wsectionstart = zeros(1,2);
  wsectionstart(1) = str2double(T{2,2});
  wsectionstart(2) = str2double(T{2,3});
  linewidth = str2double(T{1,2});
  xlabel = T{3,2};
  ```

Note that `T` must be indexed using curly braces as it is a `cell`. This requires a more properly structured input file (`test_input.txt`) than yours, laid out as follows:

```
Option,         Value1,     Value2
linewidth,      12,         -
wsectionstart,  1000000,    3000000 
xlabel,         Capture,    -
```

The commas are key, space this out how you like but the columns are read in from each comma delimiter and the rows from each row in the file.

It shouldn't matter if you use my code instead of your own, but note that one of the edits to your question replaced a comma `,` with a semi-colon `;` at the end of a line. This is the right correction to make, but you may have missed that it happened.